# Perform a reverse cumulative sum on a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cumsum

Can anyone recommend a way to do a reverse cumulative sum on a numpy array?

Where 'reverse cumulative sum' is defined as below (I welcome any corrections on the name for this procedure):

if

```
x = np.array([0,1,2,3,4])
```

then

```
np.cumsum(x)
```

gives

```
array([0,1,3,6,10])
```

However, I would like to get

```
array([10,10,9,7,4]
```

Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This does it:

```
np.cumsum(x[::-1])[::-1]
```

Comment: An equivalent way, but different syntax is:
x[::-1].cumsum()[::-1]

Comment: For anyone who wants to know, for multidimensional arrays you just need to hold any rows/columns constant i.e if x is a two dimensional array then `np.cumsum(x[:, ::-1], axis=1)[:, ::-1]` sums along the rows in reverse.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `.flipud()` for this as well, which is equivalent to `[::-1]`
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flipud.html

```
In [0]: x = np.array([0,1,2,3,4])

In [1]: np.flipud(np.flipud(x).cumsum())
Out[1]: array([10, 10,  9,  7,  4]
```

`.flip()` is new as of NumPy 1.12, and combines the `.flipud()` and `.fliplr()` into one API.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html

This is equivalent, and has fewer function calls:

```
np.flip(np.flip(x, 0).cumsum(), 0)
```

Comment: FYI. I found these solutions twice as slow as `np.cumsum(x[::-1])[::-1] ` for small arrays (<50 elements).  There must be more overhead I suppose.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The answers given so far seem to be all inefficient if you want the result stored in the original array.  As well, if you want a copy, keep in mind this will return a view not a contiguous array and [`np.ascontiguousarray()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ascontiguousarray.html) is still needed.

How about

```
view=np.flip(x, 0)
np.cumsum(view, 0, out=view)
#x contains the reverse cumsum result and remains contiguous and unflipped
```

This modifies the flipped view of `x` which writes the data properly in reverse order back into the original `x` variable.  It requires no non-contiguous views at the end of execution and is about as speed efficient as possible.  I am guessing numpy will never add a reversecumsum method namely because the technique I describe is so trivially and efficiently possible.  Albeit, it might be ever so slightly more efficient to have the explicit method.

Otherwise if a copy is desired, then the extra flip is required AND conversion back to a contiguous array, mainly if it will be used in many vector operations thereafter.  A tricky part of numpy, but views and contiguity are something to be careful with if you are seriously interested in performance.