# How to sum remaining columns values in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I was wondering how to add a column "total" to a pandas dataframe, containing the sum of all rows beyond that particular row.
To clarify what I mean: I already have "index" and "number", and I want to create "total":

```
index   number    total
0       5         18 (5+7+3+1+2)
1       7         13 (7+3+1+2)
2       3         6 (3+1+2)
3       1         3 (1+2)
4       2         2
```

I have no idea where to start, some help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Perform a reverse cumulative sum on a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541618/perform-a-reverse-cumulative-sum-on-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a numpy based one using [`np.triu`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html) to build an upper triangular matrix from `number`, and then adding along the second axis (*note*: for larger arrays, the `cumsum` approach in the dupe `np.cumsum(a[::-1])[::-1]`  is much more efficient)

```
a = df.number.to_numpy()
df['total'] = np.triu(a).sum(1)
```

---

```
print(df)

   index  number  total
0      0       5     18
1      1       7     13
2      2       3      6
3      3       1      3
4      4       2      2
```

Answer (score 0):

One quick solution is using [`pandas.Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) on the rows that are order-inverted with `[::-1]`

```
df['total'] = df['number'].iloc[::-1].cumsum()[::-1]
```

Output

```
#    index  number  total
# 0      0       5     18
# 1      1       7     13
# 2      2       3      6
# 3      3       1      3
# 4      4       2      2
```