# How to convert [a,b,c] to [a+b+c, b+c, c] in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, torch

If I have an array [a,b,c], how can I convert it to [a+b+c, b+c, c] in the most efficient way?

(a, b, c) are floats.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Perform a reverse cumulative sum on a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541618/perform-a-reverse-cumulative-sum-on-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.cumsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
print(np.cumsum(a[::-1])[::-1])
# Outputs [6 5 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `numpy.cumsum()` on the reversed array, then reverse it again. `cumsum([a,b,c])` returns `[a,a+b,a+b+c]`.

```
import numpy as np

x = [3,7,14]

y = np.cumsum(x[::-1])[::-1]

print(y)
```